# Why Notion homepage keeps css style inside HTML div

Tags: html, css

It's commonly agreed that it's a bad practice to keep css style inside div for a large project. One should keep a separate CSS file.

However, i came across [Notion](http://notion.so) homepage, it's a beautiful website with good performance. Inspecting the webpage, i see a lot of lines like:

```
<div class="notion-app-inner notion-light-theme" style="
color: rgb(55, 53, 47); 
fill: currentcolor; 
line-height: 1.5; 
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, "Apple Color Emoji", Arial, sans-serif, "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol"; 
-webkit-font-smoothing: auto;">
```

My question is why the site keeps the css style inside the div instead of a separate css file? (or it is a result of some react practice?) What's the reason for doing it?

I understand why it's a good practice in general to keep css in a separate file. I would like to know why Notion use the opposite practice? The engineers behind the site is clearly knows what they are doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Style attribute vs setting ID and external Css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403349/style-attribute-vs-setting-id-and-external-css)

Comment: Not really. I guess i should phrase it as: in what situation would you keep it inside the div (for large complete website like notion)?

Comment: I understand your question, really. It seems that all the guys who answered your question didn't understand what you are asking :))

Answer (score 1):

I also looked for the answer for your question. I think [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/improve-site-performance-inlining-css/) is helpful for you to understand why we can improve the site's performance by inlining CSS. Below is my summary:

1. To prevent [render-blocking resource](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css). The site only needs to request to the server once (for html files), they don't need to check `<head>` to request other times for css files.
2. Notion might already check the performace and compared between using inline and not using inline. I think they chosed the better one.
3. You should (but not always) use inline. Why? Because it may lead to First [First Contentful Paint](https://web.dev/first-contentful-paint/) (FCP) -- because there are some things duplicated (in style), the browser takes much time to render again and again the same things for all DOM elements. As you can see, notion doesn't apply inline CSS for all of their elements, they use classes also. However, when you [check their site speed test](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=notion.so) with Google's PageSpeed Insight, the first problem is FCP and the score is really really bad!!!

For me, the main problem Notion chose this way is the performance. They handle their site with components (all are in `div` even for headings,...). They depend too much on the styling of `div`s to make them become other HTML parts. These components are not always their, they appear when you add them, check them,... Notion also save your works automatically every second,... You can imagine the number of requests their server must listen to. That's why the performce (server side) is the most important thing they considered, I think.

Hope I can help and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to keep the css in a separate style sheet since it's much easier to maintain.
Going through the HTML file to restyle the page is simply not efficient enough.

**Also**, If you want to have multiple elements with the same attributes, doing the styling on the specific element would take much more time.

Comment: if you were to build a website, would you use separate css or inside the div? (The website has a lot of same attributes and styling)

Comment: @jazzfaz, I would **always** use a separate css file. In rare cases I would use it directly in the HTML under the circumstances that there are only one small part of the website that needs it. However, that's bad practise. You should always use separate css-file :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a component or element created by a function. They call the function to produce the div tag with all the styling. They probably don't look at the html file being produced just the DOM and functionality since it being produce by a javascript file in the backend.
Maybe this code was originally copied and embedded on a webpage/blog, etc.. Without the inline styling the embedded code object would look clunky and awkward(probably way to large). Remember inline styling overrides .css file styling unless !important is used in the .css file styling. Hope this helps:)

Comment: You mean the inline styling is part of the original code or just a result of the reverse engineering from the inspector? Why would one use inline not @media to deal with responsiveness?

Comment: The div has two classes... so this styling is to override the .css file styling.

Answer (score -1):

To style your html file,you need css.So,u can make a separate css file and then link it to the html file in link tag.Like

.You have to put this tag in between header tag.Thus,you can apply css styling to any html file.

Comment: You don't need to use CSS though, @jazzfaz wanted to know why they chose not to in this case and instead crammed everything into the element's style.  I don't think there's a good answer to the initial question honestly but this isn't what he asked.

Answer (score -2):

Just think: You have more than 5 card items on different pages and all. If you are adding CSS to all div element you have lots of repeated code on every page. If you are going to update the card design then you will need to edit each of them manually which is not good idea. That's why you should use a separate CSS file to manage your code easier.

Answer (score -2):

create a style.css file like below, and import it

like below into your html page in head section;

html page import row:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

style.css:

```
.notion-app-inner notion-light-theme {
    color: rgb(55, 53, 47); 
    fill: currentcolor; 
    line-height: 1.5; 
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, "Apple Color Emoji", Arial, sans-serif, "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol"; 
    -webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.